# World Space in transformation constraint not working as expected

Tags: constraints

Relatively new to constraints and trying to make it so that moving the cube along the X axis makes the monkey rotate along the world's X axis.

[image: Constraint setup]

No matter what kind of combination I choose for the target and owner spaces the head keeps rotating along the local X axis.

[image: Rotation]

The only solution I've found is applying the rotation but what if I don't want to?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Y rotation instead, change X rotation back to 0, change Y rotation to 90, then change the Y >> Y box to X >> Y. Now suzanne will rotate on the world X axis ( her Y axis).

Comment: But the world X axis is not parallel to Suzanne's Y axis. Now she is only rotating on the Y axis and directly rotating Suzanne on the world's X axis still yields a different rotation (R + X while on global transform)

Comment: Ok, It was hard to tell from your pics, so she is actually rotated maybe 60d on the world Z axis ? You could try setting all the rotations to 90, and all the 'Source' mappings to X, but I don't think that rotation is interpolated. Oh, and set suzannes rotation mode to 'Quaternion'.

Comment: I will try to make some videos/gifs to make a better explanation of what I'm trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

So first, it's an unparented monkey.  So its local space *is* the world space.  Second, the constraint is operating in "default" order, which should be XYZ Euler.  The constraint operates by replacing (offsetting) its rotation triplets, not by rotating it in some axis after its initial rotationn.  When we give it Z rotation by transforming it and X rotation via the constraint, those are still happening in the Euler order of XYZ, so the constraint is effectively operating before its transform.

To make it do what you want, change the "order" on the transformation constraint, maybe to ZYX Euler.